# C++ Access Violation writing Location 0x00B0A654

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ifstream

So I'm developing tile engine for a game built-in C++. as part of this, I want to store and load tiles from a .txt file saved in the game's directory.

this code saves a level

```
void LevelManager::SaveToFile(char * FileName)
{
    ofstream File(FileName);
    File.clear();
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < 300; y++) {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < 300; x++) {

            File << TileGrid[x][y].PhysicsNumber << " ";
            File << TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopLeft << " ";
            File << TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopRight << " ";
            File << TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomLeft << " ";
            File << TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomRight << " ";
        }
        File <<  "\n";
    }
    File.close();
}
```

and then the following code reads the file

```
void LevelManager::LoadFromFile(char * FileName)
{
    ifstream infile;
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    infile.open(FileName);
    while (y < 300) {
        char Current = 0;
        infile.read(&Current, 1);
        if (Current == 10) {
            y++; 
            x = 0;
        }
        else if (Current == 32) {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 5) counter = 1;
            x++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1) {
            TileGrid[x][y].PhysicsNumber = (TileGrid[x][y].PhysicsNumber * 10) + Current - 48;
        }
        else if (counter == 2) {
                TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopLeft = (TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopLeft * 10) + Current - 48;
        }
        else if (counter == 3) {
            TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopRight = (TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopRight * 10) + Current - 48;
        }
        else if (counter == 4) {
            TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomLeft = (TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomLeft * 10) + Current - 48;
        }
        else if (counter == 5) {
            TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomRight = (TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomRight * 10) + Current - 48;
        }

    }

    infile.close();
}
```

Visual Studio is giving me this error "Access Violation writing Location 0x00B0A654"

research online suggests that I'm reading data that doesn't exist but I'm unsure on how I can fix that.

Edit: forgot to mention that the error only occurs when writing the saving code.

Comment: And what is `TileGrid`? Do you allocate enough items in there to access `TileGrid[x][y]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: TileGrid is a 2-dimensional array of data type Tile. Tile is a struct with an int PhysicsNumber and a graphic tile struct called GT which has four ints

Comment: I have to confess that I'm not really getting what your'e doing here, it seems overly complicated to me. Why not do the same y/x loops with the same order for loading, just with `>>` instead of `<<`? (encapsulated with `try/catch` to catch file errors). I assume this would simplify things enormously.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean? I do now realize I forgot to specify that the error comes from my loading code and not my saving code. maybe if you explain what has confused you I can explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: OK, I'll try to write an answer with a simplified code. But that might not fix your error (because it is perhaps somewhere else, like in an insufficent allocation, like VTT already mentioned)

Comment: nevermind, I found the source of the issue. inside the if statement (Current = 32) the line x++; needs to be inside the if statement (counter > 5)

Comment: Great :) But I have already begun to write an example, might be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other people already stated, a debugger is a great help in case of an error. Fortunately you have already found the error.

Nevertheless, I think your code can be simplified. Overly complicated code is often a frustrating source of errors, and so it's always a major goal to keep the code as simple as possible. Your `LoadFromFile()` function is really complicated; I'm having a hard time to understand what's happening there. And you probably had too... like you said, the error was somewhere inside of your `Current`, `x` and so on declaration and `if`'s.

Here is a much simpler and much more understandable version of your `LoadFromFile()` / `SaveToFile()` functions.

```
void LevelManager::SaveToFile( char * FileName ) {
    try {
        std::ofstream file( FileName );
        file.clear();
        for(unsigned y = 0; y < 300; y++) {
            for(unsigned x = 0; x < 300; x++) {
                file << TileGrid[x][y].PhysicsNumber << "\n";
                file << TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopLeft << "\n";
                file << TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopRight << "\n";
                file << TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomLeft << "\n";
                file << TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomRight << "\n";
            }
        }
        file.close();
    } catch(...) {} //TODO: catch & evaluate file errors
}

void LevelManager::LoadFromFile( char * FileName ) {
    try {
        std::ifstream file( FileName );
        for(unsigned y = 0; y < 300; y++) {
            for(unsigned x = 0; x < 300; x++) {
                file >> TileGrid[x][y].PhysicsNumber;
                file >> TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopLeft;
                file >> TileGrid[x][y].GT.TopRight;
                file >> TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomLeft;
                file >> TileGrid[x][y].GT.BottomRight;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    } catch(...) {} //TODO: catch & evaluate file errors
}
```

This time, the `LoadFromFile()` is much easier to understand. And you could even simplify this more by writing an operator, which pushes/pops a complete TileGrid element to/from a stream.

I have roughly tested this code in a test environment; please let me know if you need the whole file.

Comment: okay, I have one question, if I store the value 10, will it read that as a 10 or as 1 and 0 separately? I was under the impression the latter would be true and that was why I complicated the code, to prevent that situation

Comment: The numbers are read in one go, if you separate them with `\n`. So if you `<<` a `10`, you will also get a `10` on `>>`.

Comment: right, so this is using a different storage format to what I designed originally? that could make it difficult to program around, as the format you described has very limited readability.

Comment: Yes it is different - you didn't mention that the file format is a fixed requirement ;)
Nevertheless, I'd prefer the simplicity. If you need a human readable format, you could debug dump the values to a separate log file, when necessary.

Comment: your solution is probably better, but this is an assignment so readability is key, that said considering I managed to fix my code I'll keep it for the sake of marks. thanks though I think I have a better understanding of how file reading works thanks to you, I tend to avoid it because the code often looks unfriendly.